# measure tool and layer search overlap -qgis2web

Tags: openlayers, qgis2web

why is it that when I activate measure tool and layer search in Ol3 qgis2web, they overlap on each other. Any solution please

Comment: I'm afraid it works for me - they don't overlap. Can you confirm which versions of QGIS and qgis2web you are using? And do you have any other options selected which add widgets to the map which could be causing yours to overlap? Perhaps a screenshot would help (or a link to the live map, if possible).